# Tridion Event extension : Get the Components used in page as they published

Tags: 2013, event-system

We have a Page with metadata for JS/XSLT/CSS and when the Page gets published, the underlying JS/XSLT/CSS too gets published. To publish the JS/XSLT/CSS, we are using `engine.AddBinary()`.

We have an event extension that logs the published item information. When we publish the Page which we have described above, it is logging only the Page details and not the JS/XSLT/CSS details though they are getting published as part of Page publish.

We are using the code snippet as given below to get the processed items from the `PublishTransaction` object. If the Page has any Dynamic Components inside Page's Component Presentations, then those Dynamic Components are available under `ProcessedItems` object. However I am looking for CSS/JS/XSLT too in the list as they are getting published as part of the Page.

Example:

```
PublishTransaction transaction
IList<IdentifiableObject> items = transaction.Items;
foreach (IdentifiableObject item in items)
{
    IList<PublishContext> publishContexts = transaction.PublishContexts;
    foreach (PublishContext publishContext in publishContexts)
    {
        IList<ProcessedItem> oProcessedItems = publishContext.ProcessedItems;
        foreach (ProcessedItem oProcessedItem in oProcessedItems)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me in placing the correct API call to satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The `ProcessedItems` will contain items that are explicitly published, which is why you will find your Page there and also any Dynamic Component Presentation that is part of the Page, but not your Multimedia Components that are published via the `AddBinary()` call.

Frank van Puffelen has written a [Binary Event Tracker](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx) and his extension adds two things for implicitly published binaries:

1. Implicitly published binaries show up as published
2. Binaries that are removed from the web server will show up as unpublished

For more details, read his entire description on [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx), where you can also download the source code of his extension.